# Create a continuously rotating square on the screen using animateKeyframesWithDuration

Tags: ios, animation, swift, rotation, repeat

I tried to use the code below to create a continuously rotating square on the screen. But I don't know why the rotational speed is changing. How could I change the code to make the rotational speed invariable? I tried different `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions`, but seems none of them work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let square = UIView()
    square.frame = CGRect(x: 55, y: 300, width: 40, height: 40)
    square.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(square)

    let duration = 1.0
    let delay = 0.0
    let options = UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.Repeat
        UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: {
        let fullRotation = CGFloat(M_PI * 2)

        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 1/3, animations: {
            square.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1/3 * fullRotation)
        })                        
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(1/3, relativeDuration: 1/3, animations: {
            square.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(2/3 * fullRotation)
        })                        
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(2/3, relativeDuration: 1/3, animations: {
            square.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3/3 * fullRotation)
        })
        }, completion: {finished in
        })
    }
```

Comment: 1/3 gives a different result to 1.0/3.0. Is that the problem?

Comment: Tried to change the 9th line to
`let options = UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.CalculationModeLinear|UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.Repeat`
but does not help

Comment: Tried to change all 1/3 to 1.0/3.0 . but does not help

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Keyframe? would a UIView.animateWithDuration(duration:delay:options:animations:completion:) work. I also had trouble with the keyframe version, but got this version to work.

Comment: @JMFR   I'm using Keyframe since I found animateWithDuration won't work. Because the start and end state of a full 360' rotation are equivalent, Swift did not interpolate anything in between. Could you please provide more details if you got the animateWithDuration version work?

Comment: @NixiliaAK I will post the animateWithDuration source later today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's really odd... `UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration` isn't working as I would expect it to with `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.CalculationModeLinear|UIViewKeyframeAnimationOpti‌​ons.Repeat` passed in with options.

If you use the non-block method of creating a keyframe animation (see below) the rotation repeats as expected.

If I find out why the block-based option isn't working I'll try and remember to update answer here too!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let square = UIView()
    square.frame = CGRect(x: 55, y: 300, width: 40, height: 40)
    square.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(square)

    let fullRotation = CGFloat(M_PI * 2)

    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation()
    animation.keyPath = "transform.rotation.z"
    animation.duration = 2
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    animation.values = [fullRotation/4, fullRotation/2, fullRotation*3/4, fullRotation]

    square.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "rotate")

}
```

Answer (score 10):

I faced same problem before, this is how I make it work:

**Swift 2**

```
let raw = UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.Repeat.rawValue | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear.rawValue
let options = UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: raw)
```

**Swift 3,4,5**

```
let raw = UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions.repeat.rawValue | UIView.AnimationOptions.curveLinear.rawValue
let options = UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: raw)
```

I figured this problem out just before gave it up. I don't think there is doc about it, but it just work.

Comment: you are my hero this day. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Add `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear` do your keyframe options. The default behavior for UIView animations is to "ease in/out" of the animation. i.e., start slow, go up to speed, then slow down again just near the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the options to
"        let options = UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.CalculationModeLinear|UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.Repeat"
but seems got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU, this is happening because the default animation curve is `UIViewAnimationOption.CurveEaseInOut`.

Unfortunately,  `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions` doesn't have options for changing the curve, but you can add them manually!

Use this extension:

**Swift 2**

```
extension UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions {
    static var CurveEaseInOut: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions { return UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut.rawValue) }
    static var CurveEaseIn: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions { return UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn.rawValue) }
    static var CurveEaseOut: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions { return UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut.rawValue) }
    static var CurveLinear: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions { return UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear.rawValue) }
}
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
extension UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions {
    static var curveEaseInOut: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions { return UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue) }
    static var curveEaseIn: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions { return UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn.rawValue) }
    static var curveEaseOut: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions { return UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut.rawValue) }
    static var curveLinear: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions { return UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveLinear.rawValue) }
}
```

Now you can use curve options in `UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration` method

**Swift 2**

```
let keyframeOptions: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions = [.Repeat, .CurveLinear]
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: keyframeOptions, animations: {
    // add key frames here
}, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
let keyframeOptions: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions = [.repeat, .curveLinear]
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: keyframeOptions, animations: {
    // add key frames here
}, completion: nil)
```