# Swift Continuous Rotation Animation not so continuous

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation

Here is my code. Intent is to continuously rotate the UIImageView named swirls[l]. However, there is a small pause between every rotation start/end. I have gone through every single animation tutorial but cant figure out what the mistake is?

```
let fullRotation = CGFloat(M_PI * 2)

    let duration = 2.0
    let delay = 0.0
    let options = UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.CalculationModeLinear

    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 1/3, animations: {
            swirls[l].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1/3 * fullRotation)
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(1/3, relativeDuration: 1/3, animations: {
            swirls[l].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(2/3 * fullRotation)
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(2/3, relativeDuration: 1/3, animations: {
            swirls[l].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3/3 * fullRotation)
        })

        }, completion: {finished in 
    })
```

EDIT: I see that it has been suggested that a previous solution is available, but it simply does not work for continuous uninterrupted rotation. The only trick that worked for me is the answer that I chose below. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a continuously rotating square on the screen using animateKeyframesWithDuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665124/create-a-continuously-rotating-square-on-the-screen-using-animatekeyframeswithdu)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your code, but I've implemented continuous rotation using this method,

```
@IBAction func rotateView(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.spinningView.transform = self.spinningView.transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2)
    }) { (finished) -> Void in
        self.rotateView(sender: sender)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat rather then starting animation again in completion handler

Comment: @zellb, that doesn't work in this situation since I'm only going 1/4 of the way around with each call. Besides, that's what the OP is doing, and it results in a delay before the next animation starts.

Comment: @rdelmar: I tried this but I get no rotation at all.

Comment: @TPos, I don't know why that would be without seeing how you implemented it. It works fine in my hands.

Comment: @rdelmar: Actually your method does work!! I had initially made a typo.

Comment: I did exactly same thing except the "options: .curveLinear" part which actually did the trick.

Answer (score 60):

Try below extension for swift 4.

```
extension UIView {
    func rotate360Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 3) {
        let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(Double.pi * 2)
        rotateAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        rotateAnimation.duration = duration
        rotateAnimation.repeatCount=Float.infinity
        self.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

For start rotation.

```
MyView.rotate360Degrees()
```

And for Stop.

```
MyView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

You can use `UIButton`, `UILabel` and many more.

Comment: I love it! Honestly this should be the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Worked like a charm... :)

Comment: This solution is great, makes your VC less messy

Comment: Perfect, I tried different solutions but this is the best.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to continuous rotate Button or View and stop that rotation whenever you want then you can try  this:
For start rotation:

```
@IBOutlet weak var RotateBtn: UIButton!
var timeTimer: Timer?

viewDidLoad()
{
  self.rotateView()
  timeTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.rotateView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func rotateView()
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.RotateBtn.transform = self.RotateBtn.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_4))
    })
}
```

If you want to stop rotation then use:

```
@IBAction func StopBtn_Pressed(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
   timeTimer?.invalidate()
   self.RecordBtn.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```