# Drawing a circular loader

Tags: ios, swift

I have to create a circular loader as per below image (Front is thicker than tail)

[image]

I am able to create a circular progress bar and also provided rotation animation.

below is code for circle

```
func circleFrame() -> CGRect {
  var circleFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2 * circleRadius, height: 2 * circleRadius)
  let circlePathBounds = circlePathLayer.bounds
  circleFrame.origin.x = circlePathBounds.midX - circleFrame.midX
  circleFrame.origin.y = circlePathBounds.midY - circleFrame.midY
  return circleFrame
}

func circlePath() -> UIBezierPath {
  return UIBezierPath(ovalIn: circleFrame())
}
```

Using above code I can create a circle of equal width but not like as displayed image.

Please guide me how to create a loader like above image (tail is thinner than front). Any idea or suggestion would be great.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43835940/1630618).  It's similar to yours.  Instead of varying the color when drawing the circle segments, you'd change the line width.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach might be to create the image you want to display and then rotate it, rather than trying to draw it from scratch.

I haven't tried the following tutorial but I'm including it as a sample of how this might be done:
https://bencoding.com/2015/07/27/spinning-uiimageview-using-swift/

Note that the GitHub version (linked on that page) includes a Swift 4 update.