# Infinite rotation around point without of rotating view around itself?

Tags: swift, rotation, infinite-loop, cgaffinetransform, cabasicanimation

Code for rotation took from here:

[Swift Continuous Rotation Animation not so continuous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964346/swift-continuous-rotation-animation-not-so-continuous)

```
extension UIView {
    func rotate360Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 3) {
        let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(Double.pi * 2)
        rotateAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        rotateAnimation.duration = duration
        rotateAnimation.repeatCount=Float.infinity
        self.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

The problem is when I rotate this view around a pivot point this view is rotated around its center too and so square view becomes similar to rhombus. For example, if this view contains text then text is rotated too and becomes less readable.

How to solve this issue? I know if I had used `CGAffineTransform` this problem would have been resolved somehow by multiplying various transformations. But `CGAffineTransform` is broken on restarting `animateWithDuration`. In the same time I don't know how and what to do with `CABasicAnimation` at all.

Comment: Do you mean you want to *translate* the view along a circular path? [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38416742/5133585)